# Magento 1 php script product in stock sent email

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, script

I would like a php script that when specific products, which I define, have a qty of higher than 0. I automatically receive an e-mail from this.

Anyone have an idea how I can easily make a script out of this? My current script looks like this, but this will always sent a email.

I would only like to sent a email when the foreach got products.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '4G');

require('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$productIds = array(500004,540603,529536,513045);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1','left');

$message =
        "
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <table name='contact_seller' style='border-collapse:separate';> 
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Productname</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                    </tr>    
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
                    foreach($products as $product){
                    if ($product->getQty() > 0){
                        $message .="<tr>
                            <td>" .$product->getSku()."</td>
                            <td>".round($product->getQty())."</td>
                        </tr>";
                     }
                     }
                $message .= "</tbody>
            </table>     
        </body>
        </html>";


$to      = 'test@test.com';
$subject = 'Subject';

$headers = 'From: test@test.com' . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
    'Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n".
    'Reply-To: test@test.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it sth different from standard Product Alert in magento?

`System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Product Alerts -> Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock`?

Comment: No that's not working well, I need a custom script. See my edit and current code.